# Magento categories no longer have any relteing data or sub categories

Tags: php, mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

My issue is that the categories i use in magento overnight seem to have lost all there sub categories and the data relating to the categories themselves, i also cannot create,edit or do anything with the first level of categories i have access to, however in the database in catalog_category_entity there seems to be all the categories data. However the categories still work and appear on the front end of the website.

I have tried the following: refreshing all indexes and caches, tried to remake categories(nothing will save on that page). I have not installed any extensions within the last 3 months so it shouldn't be a confliction.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your problem, but you can try like below. I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/category/edit.phtml
```

Find this code and remove it:

```
toolbarToggle.stop();
```

and

```
toolbarToggle.start();
```

Then refresh your cache. I hope this can help you.